# sbt console how to update to latest Scala version?

Tags: sbt

I have installed sbt using the instructions in [Installing sbt on Linux](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html).

```
$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version **0.13.8**
```

```
$ sbt console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
```

How to configure (or update) sbt so that `sbt console` uses the latest Scala version **2.11.6**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a `build.sbt` file and enter the `scalaVersion`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
```

Run `sbt console` in the same directory with your `build.sbt` and it will load the version you specified.

```
...:sbttest/ $ sbt console                                                                                                                                                                                                    [10:55:53]
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/.../.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to sbttest (in build file:/tmp/sbttest/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Comment: works perfectly. At first `sbt console` the new Scala 2.11.6 binaries and dependencies are downloaded and installed automatically. Thank you very much sir for your help.

Answer (score 6):

> Run sbt console in the same directory with your build.sbt and it will load the version you specified.

You can also place the `build.sbt` file in the `.sbt/0.13/` directory:

```
cat <<END > ~/.sbt/0.13/build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
END
```

Then, executing `sbt console` from anywhere else will give you your favourite version of `scala`.  (If there is a local `build.sbt` file in the directory you execute `sbt` from, the locally specified version will override the global).

Comment: For windows go to the .sbt folder (by default at `C:\Users\<user>\.sbt\0.13` )  and create a new build.sbt file with the scalaVersion information. This still requires manual update every time a new scala version is out; would be nice to have a way to point it to "latest".

Answer (score 3):

`sbt ++ 2.11.11 console`

Change 2.11.11 to the Scala version of your choice.

From `sbt help ++`:

```
++ <scala-version> [<command>]
    Changes the Scala version and runs a command.

    Sets the `scalaVersion` of all projects to <scala-version> and 
    reloads the build.
    If <command> is provided, it is then executed.

++ [<scala-version>=]<scala-home> [<command>]
    Uses the Scala installation at <scala-home> by configuring the 
    scalaHome setting for
    all projects.

    If <scala-version> is specified, it is used as the value of the 
    scalaVersion setting.
    This is important when using managed dependencies.  This version 
    will determine the
    cross-version used as well as transitive dependencies.

    If <command> is provided, it is then executed.

    See also `help +`
```

Comment: Wow this is a geeky solution. Thank you very much.